# append row count to a file in dos

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

Is it possible to get the number of rows in a file excluding the first row as it has column names and append the RowCount at the end of the input file.

I tried findstr to get the rowcount but unable to store it to a @variable and append at the end of the input file a line as - Row Count : @variable.

Comment: What programming language are you using? Do you really mean MS-DOS, an obsolete 16-bit operating system, or do you mean from the Windows command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on Windows, and not MS-DOS.

```
@echo off
set "file=test.txt"
for /f %%N in ('type "%file%" ^| find /v /c ""') do set /a cnt=%%N-1
>>"%file%" echo %cnt%
```